# Automatically add drawables in android

Tags: java, android, android-drawable

I came here because i have not found any solution on internet.

I have added some pictures in my `drawable` folder.

These pictures are named like that :

```
R.drawable.item_1
R.drawable.item_2
...
```

I would like to create a method to load all that pictures to an array, but I don't know where to begin.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I think there's no way to do that.

Instead, you could use a switch-case or if-else statement as follows:

```
    if(var.toString().equals("item_1")) 
        drawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.item_1);
    else if(var.toString().equals("item_2")) 
        drawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.item_2);
    ...
```

Comment: i will try to create a loop with a variable using your if :D

Answer (score 0):

You can put pictures in array as simple as:

```
Resources res=c.getResources();     
int[] images={R.drawable.item_1, R.drawable.item_2, R.drawable.item_3};
```

Comment: If i have 3 pictures it's good but i have 50 ^^ and maybe more. With your method i have to add each one manually

Answer (score 0):

I've solved my problem with this if this can help someone else

```
Field[] fields = R.drawable.class.getFields();
private int[] mImageIds = new int[50];


    mContext = c;

    for (Field field : fields) {
        if (field.getName().contains("item_")) {
            try {
                mImageIds[i] = mContext.getResources().getIdentifier(field.getName(), "drawable", mContext.getPackageName());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            i++;
        }
```